# tinymce/wp_editor looses line breaks when content is shown in front-end

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm replacing a regular old textarea input with a wp_editor tinymce area, but it doesn't seem to pass the line breaks/paragraph tags to the front-end :(

More details: I'm using a custom admin panel, and these options are registered in functions.php with

```
register_setting( 'setting-group-name', 'setting-name' );
```

Then set using

```
wp_editor( get_option('setting-name'), setting-name, $settings = array( 'textarea_rows' => 7 ) );
```

...and recalled in the theme using

```
<p><?php echo get_option('setting-name'); ?></p>
```

The odd thing is that the line breaks and are remembered in the admin panel, but not represented on the site.

To confirm, the plain-text textarea I used previously works great, I can add markup and it's saved and displays well. When I swap it out for the wp_editor approach, it doesn't display properly on the front-end.

Any ideas?

Comment: Line break issues are often down to the `wpautop` setting (and function). Looks like it defaults to true for `wp_editor`, so not sure why it's not working.  What happens if you wrap your output in a call to [wpautop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)? Or apply `the_content` filter to it (eg `echo apply_filters('the_content', get_option('setting-name'))`)?

Comment: Amazing :)

I didn't have any luck adding apply_filter to the either in functions.php or just before the echo in the front-end, eg.

`apply_filters('the_content', get_option('sb2_abouttext'));
echo get_option('sb2_abouttext');`

...but using

`echo do_shortcode( wpautop( get_option( 'sb2_abouttext' ) ) );`

 worked great. Thanks so much!